# Normalize the incoming data

Tags: sql, database-design, ssis, sql-server-2012

I have source that contains data like this

```
+-------+-------+---------+--------------+----------------+-------------+--------------+
| ID    | Name  | Type    | Product_Area | Product_status | Spare_value | Service_Time |
+-------+-------+---------+--------------+----------------+-------------+--------------+
| 10001 | Motor | Product | Electrical   | Active         |             |              |
+-------+-------+---------+--------------+----------------+-------------+--------------+
| 10002 | Fan   | Product | Mechanical   | Running        |             |              |
+-------+-------+---------+--------------+----------------+-------------+--------------+
| 10003 | Screw | Spare   |              |                | 10          |              |
+-------+-------+---------+--------------+----------------+-------------+--------------+
| 10004 | Nut   | Spare   |              |                | 20          |              |
+-------+-------+---------+--------------+----------------+-------------+--------------+
| 10005 | Kit   | Service |              |                |             | 1 year       |
+-------+-------+---------+--------------+----------------+-------------+--------------+
| 10006 | Oil   | Service |              |                |             | 6 months     |
+-------+-------+---------+--------------+----------------+-------------+--------------+
```

I have to normalize this and put into different table. Because the first 3 columns are common for all types, `Product_Area` and `Product_status` will only come for Product type. Similarly `Spare_value` and `service_time` is for Spare and Service respectively. The requirement is to create a UID and map that in other table like below.

`MASTER`

```
+-----+-------+-------+---------+
| UID | ID    | Name  | Type    |
+-----+-------+-------+---------+
| 1   | 10001 | Motor | Product |
| 2   | 10002 | Fan   | Product |
| 3   | 10003 | Screw | Spare   |
| 4   | 10004 | Nut   | Spare   |
| 5   | 10005 | Kit   | Service |
| 6   | 10006 | Oil   | Service |
+-----+-------+-------+---------+
```

`PRODUCT`

```
+-----+--------------+----------------+
| UID | Product_Area | Product_status |
+-----+--------------+----------------+
| 1   | Electrical   | Active         |
| 2   | Mechanical   | Running        |
+-----+--------------+----------------+
```

`SPARE`

```
+-----+-------------+
| UID | Spare_value |
+-----+-------------+
| 3   | 10          |
| 4   | 20          |
+-----+-------------+
```

`SERVICE`

```
+-----+--------------+
| UID | Service_Time |
+-----+--------------+
| 5   | 1 year       |
| 6   | 6 months     |
+-----+--------------+
```

I have created a `IDENTITY` and created the first table `MASTER` without any issues. But I have no idea how to link and create other tables. I have created `foreign key` but still I don't know how to take the UID and map the UIDs accordingly. Please suggest.

Comment: After you've inserted the data in the first table (`master`) you can do `insert ... select ...` into other tables by joining master to source data and using filter. Can it solve you task?

Comment: This is not clear. What exactly do you mean "I have to normalize"? What exactly were you told to do given what? Where exactly are you stuck in what process? The bare word "normalize" doesn't mean a particular thing. Rearranging a table to separate subtypes is not either of the 2 things normalization is used for--to a 1NF & to higher NFs. What is the result of your research in getting unstuck? [ask] [help] [meta] [meta.se]

Answer (score 0):

Try [INSERT INTO SELECT](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert_into_select.asp) or [SELECT INTO](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_select_into.asp) :

```
INSERT INTO Product
SELECT IDENTITY(INT,1,1) AS UID, Product_Area,Product_status
FROM yourTable WHERE ID IN (10001,10002)


SELECT DISTINCT IDENTITY(int, 1, 1) AS UID,
                Spare_value
INTO   Spare
FROM yourTable


SELECT DISTINCT IDENTITY(int, 1, 1) AS UID,
                Service_Time
INTO   Service
FROM yourTable
```